# Best way to portably set compiler options like -Wall and -pedantic in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Even if I don't want to tie my CMakeLists file to a specific compiler, I still would like to enable certain options like -Wall that I know many compilers support.

Currently I am doing it like this to set the -Wall and -pedantic flags if they are accepted by the current compiler:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

check_cxx_compiler_flag(-Wall temp)
if(temp)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
endif()
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-pedantic temp)
if(temp)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pedantic")
endif()
```

Is there a better way? Or at least a nicer way to do essentially the same thing? The above is incredibly verbose and ugly for what it achieves. A much nicer command would be something like:

```
enable_cxx_compiler_flags_if_supported(-Wall -pedantic)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools) variable to set a per-compiler list of flags. (not sure if it's a _"nicer"_ way though). Otherwise, you could define a macro or a function that takes the list of required flags and applies `check_cxx_compiler_flag()` to them.

Comment: Write the function `enable_cxx_compiler_flags_if_supported` yourself. Maybe you want to add -Werror (after testing for it). Some compilers warn about flags they don't understand and you would clutter your compiler output with a host of ignored flag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested in a comment I've tried to write a function myself. I obviously don't know much CMake, but here is my try at a function that checks both that the flag is supported using check_cxx_compiler_flag and also checks that the flag isn't already set (to avoid flooding the list with duplicates).

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

function(enable_cxx_compiler_flag_if_supported flag)
    string(FIND "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" "${flag}" flag_already_set)
    if(flag_already_set EQUAL -1)
        check_cxx_compiler_flag("${flag}" flag_supported)
        if(flag_supported)
            set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${flag}" PARENT_SCOPE)
        endif()
        unset(flag_supported CACHE)
    endif()
endfunction()

# example usage
enable_cxx_compiler_flag_if_supported("-Wall")
enable_cxx_compiler_flag_if_supported("-Wextra")
enable_cxx_compiler_flag_if_supported("-pedantic")
```